# How to fill out AJAX form programmatically and scrape results?

Tags: ajax, facebook, scripting, screen-scraping

Basically, I want to use the Facebook Ads Manager Tool to estimate the number of users targeted by a particular set of targeting parameters. I know there is a published API available, but it is only usable if you are on their advertising application "whitelist." I am sure what I am asking is possible. Plus, it would be interesting to learn more about scraping.

Facebook's Ads Manager Tool is basically an AJAX UI for their ads API. In the process of creating a campaign, you can specify targeting parameters, and the page will dynamically report the number of users targeted as you modify the parameters. From what I've read on the web and here on stackOverflow, it is possible to use Firebug or a similar tool to pick apart what requests are being made by the page and to where, then mimicking these calls to get the information you want.

I'm having trouble interpreting the panels of Firebug. I think the URI I'm trying to send a request to is www.facebook.com/ajax/inventory_estimator.php, though I'm not sure how to form a call.

So, if I want to write a script or program that takes a list of words to use as keywords and returns the estimated number of users for each keyword, how could I do it?

Link to Facebook's Ads Manager Tool, Campaign Creation Page: 
http://www.facebook.com/ads/create

Comment: I am officially bad ass. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes using an extension like firebug to examine the HTTP requests is a good way to do this.

The Net tab is the one you want (last one).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried irobotsoft webscraper?  It has a good ajax support.

Check their forum here: http://irobotsoft.org/bb/YaBB.pl